# Python ioctl error on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, sockets, system-calls, ioctl

I'm trying to run the following function on a Mac and It's throwing

```
struct.pack('iL', bytes, names.buffer_info()[0])
IOError: [Errno 102] Operation not supported on socket
```

It works just fine on linux. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

---

Code:

```
def _get_interface_list():
max_iface = 32  # Maximum number of interfaces(Aribtrary)
bytes = max_iface * 32
is_32bit = (8 * struct.calcsize("P")) == 32  # Set Architecture
struct_size = 32 if is_32bit else 40

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
names = array.array('B', '\0' * bytes)
outbytes = struct.unpack('iL', fcntl.ioctl(
    s.fileno(),
    0x8912,  # SIOCGIFCONF
    struct.pack('iL', bytes, names.buffer_info()[0])
))[0]
namestr = names.tostring()
return namestr
```

Comment: Are you sure the IOCTL codes (i.e. the actual value of `SIOCGIFCONF`) are the same in OSX as in Linux?

Comment: Actually I'm not. I've tried looking around but, but I can't seem to find the documentation for Mac specific ioctl nor the flag list/hex value table. :/

Comment: Find out where the system header files are, and do a search for the text `SIOCGIFCONF` in them.

Comment: I consulted the unix man-page and it says "0x00008912" which seems to be the same as the one I've used.
I'm in the process of checking out the header files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the headerfile sys/sockio.h defines it as

"#define SIOCGIFCONF _IOWR('i', 36, struct ifconf) /*get ifnet list*/"

I have no idea what this means. (What in the world is _IOWR?)

Comment: It seems that what jweyrich says about SIOCGIFCONF isn't entirely true that OS X don't support SIOCGIFCONF. I just tried to implement it in Python with the help of ctypes and it seems to work just fine. As mentioned the Flag value isn't the same on Linux and OS X. I made a C program that converts #define SIOCGIFCONF _IOWR('i', 36, struct ifconf) to a hex-value. The value I got is 0xc00c6924, I use OS X Yosemite

Comment: @DavidRobertsson You're right about `SIOCGIFCONF`. What I did want to say is that Mac OS X doesn't support `SIOCGIFHWADDR`. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Mac OS X and other BSD systems don't support `SIOCGIFHWADDR`. You'll have to use **[getifaddrs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)**, which is now also supported by Linux, though it does not seem to be exposed by Python. However, you can use **[ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)** to accomplish that. I hope **[this example](http://kbyanc.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/python-enumerating-ip-addresses-on.html)** (BSD-style license) helps you.

Futhermore, you could simply avoid all the trouble by using **[netifaces](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces)**.

Comment: I looked at netifaces as my first option but I can't use it because of policy reasons.

I was wondering if there's a specific reason for SIOCGIFCONF not being supported in Mac OS X and other BSD systems since the function and SIOCGIFCONF are actually defined in the system libraries?

Comment: @Ayos I don't know the exact reason, but `getifaddrs` is preferred over `SIOCGIFCONF`. I did update the link for an example that actually works. You can use it as `print [str(ni) for ni in getifaddrs()]`.

Answer (score 0):

Flag value of SIOCGIFCONF is 0xc00c6924 on OS X 10.9.

*updated*

I did some minor testing and it didn't throw any errors. Im not sure if it 100% working or not but I also found this from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/ip.4.html

`where "addr" is the local IP address of the desired interface or INADDR_ANY to specify the default interface.  An interface's local IP address and multicast capability can be obtained via the SIOCGIFCONF and SIOCGIFFLAGS ioctls.  Normal applications should not need to use this option.`